# X-ray imaging and diamond

Tags: x-rays, imaging, diamond

Why doesn't diamond show up in X-ray imaging? Diamond is the hardest substance ever known, and as we know, X-ray radiation is produced when a cathode ray of high frequency hits a very high atomic mass target. But I am amazed: why doesn't diamond show up in X-ray imaging?

Comment: You are misinformed. The structure of diamond was found by x-ray crystallography . here is an image too: http://www.allposters.com/-sp/X-ray-of-hand-with-diamond-ring-Posters_i8660943_.htm . airport machines catch them : http://www.independenttraveler.com/travel-tips/air-travel/what-not-to-do-at-the-airport

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly how and to what extent diamond shows up in x-rays depends on factors such as type of x-ray apparatus, size of diamond, orientation and so on.

Carbon has an atomic mass of 12. That's fairly low.

> Diamond exhibits a bunch of unique properties such as extreme hardness, high thermal conductivity and chemical inertness. In terms of X-ray windows another property of diamond is of crucial importance: diamond consists of carbon i.e. diamond is a low Z material which is transparent to X-rays.

...

> High transmission coefficients even at low X-ray energies can be achieved by using thin diamond membranes mounted on circular silicon support disks. The thickness of these membranes can be as low as 1 µm

From http://www.diamond-materials.com/EN/products/cvd_for_xray/xray_windows.htm

---

However you can use X-rays to make useful [images of diamonds](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/X-ray-cmt/rivers/diamonds.html)

---

X-Ray absorption is related to density, diamond is about 3.5 times as dense as water.
3,500 kg/m3 or 3.5 g/cm3.

Comment: So is your conclusion **"most diamonds show up in X-Rays"** or  "most diamonds do not show up in X-Rays"?